# Helper type alias vs inheritance

Tags: c++, traits

I would like to know what should be the better practice to use when a helper trait *selects* a type that can be then used as a base for another type.

As an example, consider the following helper trait:

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Definition of TestSelect. (equiv. to std::conditional)
 */

template<bool Ok, typename T, typename F>
struct TestSelect { using Type = F; };

template<typename T, typename F>
struct TestSelect<true, T, F> { using Type = T; };
```

Now, suppose that `TestSelect` would be rather named `TypeSelect` and that the types passed as arguments to it are expect to be subclass-able...

- It will thus often be used in situations like:

```
class MyClass : TestSelect<HasConnect, Manager, Connector>::Type {}
```

The above is a purely fictive example, but this is to give a better idea of the purpose of the trait...

- To make `TestSelect` easier to use, on could define a helper alias, like so:

```
template<bool Ok, typename T, Typename F>
using TestSelectT = typename TestSelect<Ok, T, F>::Type;
```

- An other option would be – *because `T` and `F` are expected to be fully defined class types* – to make `TestSelect` inherit from the selected type, like so:

```
template<bool Ok, typename T, typename F>
struct TestSelect : F {};

template<typename T, typename F>
struct TestSelect<true, T, F> : T {};
```

I can't make up my mind and choose what seems the best option... So I'd like to know:

- What would be the best choice, and why ?

Or, if one can determine that the two option are somewhat *unrelated*:

- What are the situations within which each should be *the best choice* ?

*Thanks in advance...*

---

###### ° Update

As @NaN underlined, the two options proposed in this question lead to different results. Although they might both be used for the initial intended purpose of the issue, they are different things *(somewhat unrelated)*.

One can *imagine* that inheriting from `TestSelect` could be done as an *implementation detail* for "*some reasons*", because it would precisely be *"**an implementation detail**"* *(ie. not known from the public interface)*.

But one can clearly say that ***it wouldn't be very smart***, because it brings no benefits, and the *type alias* version better fulfill the same purpose without adding a level of inheritance.

Thus, the best option *(if one can say – because there's not really two options here)* is clearly to either:

- Directly use `TestSelect`, or
- The helper type alias.

Just to clarify a bit why/how I came up to this wired *non-choice*... *(if ever someone else, someday, come up to the same mix up in his head)*

- By looking at different STL implementations, one often can see template types deriving from an *unrelated type* passed as argument. The most common example would be an `Allocator` type. This choice is made by library implementors to benefits from EBO *(Empty Base Optimization)*. There, this choice is a perfectly good choice, because:

  1. It prevents the deriving type from having to define a member to *store* the allocator. Hence, EBO can takes place to *remove* the empty base, and the derived type size is not increased *just for it*.
  2. It is *"**an implementation detail**"* *(not public)*…

Here, inheriting from `TypeSelect` will bring no benefits at all because it does not define any member, and, it brings to the derived type no other features that might have to be accessible afterwards. Thus EBO in this case is pointless because there's *nothing to be optimized*...

*(sorry for the inconvenience)*

---

*° Note to myself:

– I should prescribe myself a little more rest between two coding sessions, shouldn't I ?*

Comment: I don't understand when or why you would want to use the second

Comment: Your second option puzzles me. "because T and F are expected to be fully defined class types" - but why? What if you want your type to be a pointer, for example? A built-in type? A `final` class?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I will clarify a little that part...

Comment: sorry i dont get it, only reason I wrote the answer was because it was too much for a comment to make the point. Don't overthink it, traits are straightforward to write and if you really ever need the second approach then just use it.

Comment: if you are looking for best practices you should look at how the example you chose is implemented in the standard library. There is no inheritance in `std::conditional`

Comment: @SergeyA and (at)NaN I'm developing a library, and it's a library tool. It purpose is precisely to be used to _select_ a base. That's an imposed requirement... If you don't want to follow this requirement, don't use this trait... ?!

Comment: @Tenphase your own question says that "often be used in situations like". It doesn't say "exclusively". If you want a trait which is used exclusively to select a base class, it is a valid use case, but in this case name should probably be `BaseSelector` or something.

Comment: @SergeyA +1 good point. You're right. Like I said to (at)NaN, I do not have much time just now, but I will come back a little later and clarify it all _(I've mixed up a bit things and oversimplified the question – resulting in this unclear context/use case)_. _(sorry for that)_

Answer (score 1):

The second is not that useful. Requiring both `T` and `F` to be useable as a base class is an unnecessary restriction. If someone wants to select between `T` and `F`as base class then they can use the first:

```
struct foo : TestSelectT< some_condition, T,F> {};
```

Hence, what the second can do you can easily do with the first. The reverse is not true. For example you cannot use the second with `T = int` or `T = some_type*`.

Its not clear why you would make the trait inherit, because using it like with the above `foo`, would not make `foo` inherit from either `T` or `F`, but it would make `foo` inherit from `TestSelect` which in turn inherits from `T` or `F`. It does not allow you to make either `T` or `F` a direct base.

---

Honestly, I think you are overthinking the issue. When this is what you want:

> [...] a helper trait selects a type that can be then used as a base for another type.

You should use `std::conditional` directly:

```
 struct foo : std::conditional_t< condition, T, F> {};
```

When the condition is complicated you might want to use a helper:

```
 template <typename T,typename F,size_t i>
 struct my_conditional<T,F,size_t i> : std::conditional<T,F,i < 42> {};
```

Note how here inheritance can be used to inherit the `type` member. You still need the alias template:

```
 template <typename T,typename F,size_t i>
 using my_conditional_t = typename my_conditional<T,F,i>::type;
```

Though the inheritance is just an implementation detail. Its a convenient way to get the `type` member. When you actually use it to inherit from `T` or `F`, you use it to inherit from `T` or `F`, not to inherit from a trait that inherits from `T` or `F`:

```
 struct foo : my_conditional_t<T,F,42> {};
```

Note that `foo` only inherits from either `T` of `F`, because thats what you wanted. It does not have other base classes.

Comment: FYI... There is something called EBO... And also, you should look at "how the standard implements" `disjunction` ie. _(carefully read the documentation – you might be surprised)_

Comment: @Tenphase I know empty base class optimization, but just because it does not occupy space doesnt mean that it is not there. Inheriting from `std::false_type` and `std::true_type` is a common pattern, but `std::false_type` and `std::true_type` arent arbitrary types. When I said "look at how the standard implementes" i was refering to `std::conditional`, ie the case you chose as example, and I don't see how inheritance brings any advantage here

Comment: @NaN see my last comment on the question.

Comment: @Tenphae I saw that comment, but I dont understand it. Look, you are asking what is better practice when choosing between two solutions that do different things. One seems to do what you want the other not. If you actually want to inherit from the trait that does inherit from either `T` of `F` then just do it, but it is not the same as only inheriting from `T` or `F`.

Comment: @Tenphase perhaps your second solution is just what you want, then just use it, but we cannot tell you which is better because there is too little context. Its not clear why you say you want to inherit from either `T` or `F` and then the solution is to inherit from another class that inherits from `T` or `F`, thats two differnt things

Comment: @Tenphase I think your misunderstanding is that "use it as a base" does not need to be part of the trait. It brings no benefit. Once you have a trait that selects between two types, you can already use it to select a type as base

Comment: @NaN Now one has something that resembles more to an "answer"... ;) – There's a very good point you raised in it. You are right _(my bad)_ when you say that there's certainly _not enough context_ in my question _(I falsely over simplified it for it not to be to long)_. But as you put several comments to which I'd like to respond, I should take a little time to review the whole thing, and, unfortunately, I am a bit busy now... _(so give me a little time, I'll come back a little later)_ – Anyway, thanks for the clarifications _(especially on the fact that I've been unclear enough)_ ;)

Comment: @NaN I think that the two last paragraphs of your answer are clearly pointing in the right direction I think. Add a little something to say that, in this case, the best _(or rather the only)_ good choice would be the helper trait, and I think it'll worth +1 and validation ;) – As a side note, `std::disjunction` does not necessarily inherit from `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) _(first sentence in "Notes")_. Thanks for your time, and to have helped me looking at it _the right way_.